# Pycharm: How do you check what git repository you're connected to?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

The answer for this might be super obvious, but I can't seem to figure out how to check what the github url is for the project that I'm in. I want to make sure I'm connected to the correct remote repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for IntelliJ but I assume it's the same for PyCharm.

In the menu, select VCS => Git => Remotes...

Or use the command line:

```
git remote show origin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the corner down

[GIT:master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElOAR.png)

Also you can see the documentation for [git in Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-git-integration.html)

Comment: This shows the branch that you're currently on. I was looking for how to get the url of the entire repository. Thanks for your response though, I appreciate it. @str had the answer I was looking for.